# How to create privileges buttons dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, windows-forms-designer

As I can create buttons automatically depending on the user who logs in, for example an administrator user is of type administrator and has all the privileges, then the admin user when login in the form should generate the privileges like buttons, how can it be done?

My login code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    if (txtUser.Text == "" || txtContrasenna.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please provide UserName and Password");
                    return;
                }
                try
                {
                    //Create SqlConnection
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where NameUser=@nameuser and Password=@password", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameuser", txtUser.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtContrasenna.Text);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                   // int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                    //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
                    if (ds.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        switch (ds.Rows[0]["UserTypeId"] as int?)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                {
                                    this.Hide();
                                   Menus.MenuSuperUser ss = new Menus.MenuSuperUser();
                                    ss.Show();
                                   // MessageBox.Show("MAMALON");

                                    break;
                                }
                            case 2:
                                {
                                    this.Hide();
                                    PantallasUsers.DashboardVendedor ss = new PantallasUsers.DashboardVendedor();
                                    ss.Show();

                                    break;
                                }
                            default:
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("NOTBABY");
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Algo esta mal, revisa tus datos.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: Why don't add controls to form and hide them by default and then make them visible based on user role?

Comment: @Xaqron Because several permissions can be added for each user role, then each permission is a button

Comment: You can try placing a `statusStrip` in your winform then add a status label that defines the roles per user and from there slowly define each permissions.

Comment: @P.Pat How do I keep the user logged in?

Comment: Can you share how the UI should look like based on the role of the user? And which part of the UI can be changed based on the permission?

Comment: @PonchRobles if your users whether it be the administrator or other roles sees `ss.Show();`, is already considered to have logged in. So unless you close `ss` form which is `Menus.MenuSuperUser` in administrators case then you can say that user is in logged in status.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create desired control
CTRL ctrl = new CTRL();

// Set properties
ctrl.SomeProperty = value;

// Where to put the control
ctrl.Location = new Point(X, Y);

Controls.Add(ctrl);
```